# How to merge variables from parallel flows in Activiti?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Currently I have a sub-process which uses fork/join mechanism to create parallel flows. Lest assume that there are two flows: **A, B**. Each of that flows takes as input variables complex object **CONTEXT**. Also each of that flows make some calculation and updates **CONTEXT** inside. As a output each of flows return updated **CONTEXT**. The problem here is that in **Join** point, last result of **CONTEXT** overrides previous one. Lets assume that flow **A** fill be finished first with result **CONTEXT_1** and flow **B** will return **CONTEXT_2**. So final result will be **CONTEXT_2** and all changes from flow **A** will be lost.

**The question here is - how to merge results from two flows?**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
From my observations passed variable (CONTEXT) from SuperProcess to SubProcess are copied(CONTEXT') and after subProcess is finished, new value of passed variable(CONTEXT') will take place of original (CONTEXT).

In the example below I mean that all passed variables have the same name.

Example:

1. SuperProcess **P1** (Variable: **CONTEXT**) calls SubProcess **P2**(variables are passed by copy);
2. SubProcess **P2** (Variable: **CONTEXT'**) creates two parallel flows(Tasks) **A**, **B**(variables are passed by copy);
3. **A** Task (Variable: **CONTEXT_1**) updates value of variable, finishes execution and returns variable;

   3.1. **CONTEXT_1** takes place of variable **CONTEXT'** so **P2** can see only this new value as names of this variables the same;
4. Meanwhile **B** Task (Variable: **CONTEXT_2**) is still working and after some time updates variable, finishes execution and returns variable;

   4.1. **CONTEXT_2** takes place of variable **CONTEXT_1** so **P2** can see only this new value as names of this variables the same;
5. SubProcess **P2** (Variable: **CONTEXT_2**) finish the execution and returns new veriable to SuperProcess.
   Result -> **CONTEXT_1** is lossed.

My aim scenario:

1. SuperProcess **P1** (Variable: **CONTEXT**) calls SubProcess **P2**(variables are passed by copy);
2. SubProcess **P2** (Variable: **CONTEXT'**) creates two parallel flows(Tasks) **A**, **B**(variables are passed by copy);
3. **A** Task (Variable: **CONTEXT_1**) updates value of variable, finishes execution and returns variable;

   3.1. **CONTEXT_1** and **CONTEXT** are merged into **CONTEXT_M1**, in other words, only new changes of **CONTEXT_1** will be applied to **CONTEXT**.
4. Meanwhile **B** Task (Variable: **CONTEXT_2**) is still working and after some time updates variable, finishes execution and returns variable;

   4.1. **CONTEXT_2** and **CONTEXT_M1** are merged  into **CONTEXT_M2**, in other words, only new changes of **CONTEXT_2** will be applied to **CONTEXT_M1** so previous update will be not lost;
5. SubProcess **P2** (Variable: **CONTEXT_M2**) finish the execution and returns new veriable to SuperProcess.
   Result -> **CONTEXT_M2**. All changes are saved.

Comment: update the variable after the join by keeping temporary variables. can you please upload your bpmn.xml for better understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After couple days of investigation we figured out that copying variables from SuperProcess to SubProcess is default behavior ([link](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCallActivityPassVariables)):

> "You can pass process variables to the sub process and vice versa. The
>   data is copied into the subprocess when it is started and copied back
>   into the main process when it ends."

As the decision we pass variables into SubProcess under different name and merge with source variable after SubProcess finish:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you say merge? What do you mean exactly?
What is your desired behavior at the emerge point?

If you want to maintain both contexts then use a map with the execution ID as the key, however, I doubt that is what you want.

Greg

Comment: I updated my question with two scenarios. Hope it will make my question more clear.